# Python trying to write string to file then read string and eval, but something went wrong

Tags: python

I am trying to write a very simple script that would simulate a pocket secretary for my homework,  but I have a small issue.
I want all my data to be saved in a file (abstract form) each time I exit the program and then when i boot it up I want to read that file, eval(stack) (basically load the data into memory) then verify if it's valid ... anything that isn't is deleted.
This is what I've done:

```
    def loadToString (stack):
        f = open ("data.txt", "w")
        load_stack = str(stack)  #convert to string
        f.write (load_stack)  #write in file
        f.close() 

    def loadFromString ():
       f = open ("data.txt", "r")
       load_stack = f.readline() #read string
       if (load_stack == "" or load_stack == " " or load_stack == None): 
           stack = []
           return stack 
      else:
          stack = eval(load_stack) #trying to convert from string to list
      f.close ()
```

My problem is when I look into the file ... it's not really a string because it lacks the apostrophes <"> thus when I try to "eval (stack)" something goes wrong and my "memory" ends up being empty (when I try to print the stack it's empty -None-)

I cannot for the life of me understand why this is happening. Also I'm ok with a quick fix (artificially adding apostrophes in the .txt file)

I have no idea how to check if a file is empty or if I read an empty line so I'd also appreciate if you could help me with the "if" statement in "loadFromString".
About eval () ... like I said this is just homework so I'm not afraid about any malicious intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle your immediate problem, change the line `load_stack = str(stack)` to `load_stack = repr(stack)`.  That will add the apostrophes.

Afterwards, you may want to look at the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) or [shelve module](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve).  Both are easy to use and will take care of many of the low level details.